# Platter-based hard drive clicking only when performing a certain type of disk write

Tags: hard-drive, firefox, storage, smart, noise

I have a 2.5" platter-based hard drive that makes a clicking sound only when performing a specific function.  Otherwise, it is very quiet.

The function is when I download a large file (over 500MB) from the internet using a web browser (Firefox, in this case).  Firefox's is set to download files to an NTFS partition on that drive.  Outside of that, I've never heard the drive make any concerning sounds.

The drive has made this sound since it was brand new.  I checked the SMART values right away, and there were no issues.  Several years later, SMART values continue to indicate no problems.

I guessed the drive would be dead or having issues within a week of owning it, but years later it still seems to work great.

What is likely causing this clicking sound, and at this point, is there any reason to be concerned about it?

Comment: What is the exact model of this disk?

Comment: @harrymc TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075

Comment: I can't find any information about this disk having any special problem that is signaled by clicks.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for checking.  Me neither.  Where did you check?  I just used a general-purpose search engine.

Comment: I did the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to be concerned after several years without any problem
(except if the disk is getting old or the clicks are much more frequent now).

This click comes from the read/write heads as they position themselves over the
drive’s hard disk platters. For some disks, this is noisier than for others.

You should only be concerned if the drive never stop clicking,
which means that it's trying to recover an unrecoverable error by slightly
repositioning the head. But in this case, there would be some trace for it
in the SMART info of the disk (which you don't have).

The clicks when writing a large amount of data might be related to the disk
being heavily fragmented, so the head needs to continuously zip from one
free disk segment to another. This case typically happens when the disk is
relatively full and has been used for years for files that are of very
different sizes (small and large).
If this bothers you, try to defragment the disk.

(As a general note, keeping a unique copy of data that you need is not recommended.
A disk that is fine today can be dead tomorrow, so never trust a single copy.)

Comment: Thanks Harry. Fragmentation is a great guess, but that's not it. According to the OS, the partition isn't fragmented at all, as it regularly gets defragmented as part of regular maintenance procedures. I really wonder why it makes that clicking sound in that one situation of writing downloads. I think it may have something to do with the fact that, for a download, I'm pretty sure data is continually appended to a file until the download completes (it's a little more complicated than that, as multiple `part` files are created during a download, but it should be 1 `part` file at a time).

Comment: Could be a deficiency in the disk driver, data not getting written to the disk in sequential order. This would have the same effect as fragmentation, the driver not detecting that a sequential write is called for, which might be more related to large files. The disk doesn't seem to have a driver, so the Windows generic driver is used, meaning that there is nothing else to do. ..more..

Comment: ..Another explanation is that the download is slow, so the disk has time to do other stuff between writes, which again causes head movements.

Comment: Those are great postulations!  I'm curious... do you know of any way to see if either are happening (I can post another question, if you prefer).

Comment: This would need a debugger for very low-level disk operations. Disk manufacturers certainly have such, but I don't know of any.

Comment: Thanks Harry.  If you think of anything, just let me know.